# Table's tr's border doesnt appear

Tags: html, css

I want the `<tr>` will have a border-bottom, but it doesnt show. Here is what I have done:  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/33/)
the code(although you can see it in the fiddle):

```
<table style="width:600px;">
  <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
    <td style="width:30%">header1</td>
    <td style="width:50%">header2</td>
    <td style="width:20%">header3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>something1</td>
    <td>something2</td>
    <td>something3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also i dont want to have the space between the bottom-border when i use `<td style="border-bottom:1px solid black">`  on the `<td>`s of the top `<tr>`

Comment: You can't style a `<tr>` tag it's only a logical grouping element for the table.

Comment: @leigero then how can i do that the top tr will have an border-bottom?

Comment: @Omer just style the top TD elements. I updated my answer to include your edited question.

Comment: @Stijn and @C Travel, look at the accepted answer of what you thought might be a duplicate of this and my accepted answer, i have already seen those threads but they were no use for me becuase no one there suggested the border-spacing:0; for the table, therfore this thread is not a dublicate

Comment: @Omer to be fair, you added that part 2 minutes ago, while our duplicate comments were 16 and 18 minutes ago. They're an exact duplicate of your original question.

Comment: yee you right, because i thought there will be another way then to add the <td>s  a border-bottom, i would have added it anyway if no one would have suggested an answer that solve it anyway. i didnt think there is a point of adding it if someone has already answer it. now i am in ban because of that, so i added it

Comment: Note that it's not true that you can't style `<tr>`s at all. For example, you can apply heights to them. But border styling has no effect on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others say, you can't style `tr` but you can do style `td`. You may do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/36/).

```
table {
    border-spacing:0;
}
td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot style a `<tr>` tag, it is only a logical grouping tag for table elements.

Since you only want the top row styled, just give the  element in the top row a specific class identifier and style that:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/41/)

**CSS**

```
table{
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
.topRow{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
    width:50%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table style="width:600px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="topRow">header1</td>
    <td class="topRow">header2</td>
    <td class="topRow">header3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>something1</td>
    <td>something2</td>
    <td>something3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```